# Conditional expressions within data.table 'by'

Tags: r, join, data.table

I have a data table as follows

```
DT <- data.table(Age = c(16,16,17,19,20,21,23,25,27,35,25,35,35),
                 Grouping = c(1,1,1,2,2,2,2,3,3,3,3,3,3),
                 Gender = c("M","F","M","M","F","F","M","F","F","M","M","M","F"),
                 Value = c(1000,2000,1500,1250,2000,3000,1000,2500,4000,1000,3500,5000,10000))
```

I want to create an output data table which calculates the proportion of unique ages where the sum of "Value" is higher for females, relative to males, for an age - all grouped by "Grouping".

That's probably a little confusing, so I'll explain the target output below:

```
Target_output <- data.table(Grouping = c(1,2,3),
                     Proportion = c(0.5,0.5,2/3))
```

Looking at a "Grouping" value of 1, we have 2 unique ages (16 and 17).
For age 16, the total sum of "Value" is 1000 for "M", and 2000 for "F", meaning that "F" is higher for that age. The other unique age is 17, for which there is only a value for "M". That means that "F" has a higher Value total for 1 out of the 2 unique ages, giving a proportion of 0.5 as the output for Grouping value '1'.

For Grouping 2, we have four rows, all of which are for unique ages in this instance. Looking at the values, "F" has the higher value in 2 out of 4 of the ages, meaning that the output is 0.5 for the second grouping.

For Grouping 3, we have 6 values, of which 3 are for unique ages - 25, 27 and 35.
For age 25, The total Value for "F" is 2500, which is lower than the 3500 total value for "M".
For 27, there is only a value for "F".
For age 35, the total is 6000 for "M" (1000 + 5000), and 10000 for "F".
Therefore, the output is 2/3, as the "F" total is higher for two out of the three unique ages for this grouping.

In the actual data set, there are multiple values per age, gender and grouping (over 1 million rows), but there is no guarantee (as per the example), that there are values for both genders for every age.

One way that I thought of doing this was to:

1. Create a data table summarised by 'Grouping' and 'Age', with the sum of 'Value' calculated. This would be calculated separately for "M" and "F" rows
2. Join the two tables on 'Grouping' and Age, and calculate the number of rows in the join where 'Value' from the Female table exceeds the 'Male'
3. Divide the output from (2) by the number of unique ages grouped by 'Grouping'

It seems a bit fiddly, and I'm wondering whether there is an easier, more efficient, way of doing this using data.table and 'by' without having to conduct joins?

Thanks,
Phil

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe try something like:

```
DT[, .(Value=sum(Value)), keyby=.(Grouping, Age, Gender)][, 
    .(Gender=Gender[which.max(Value)]), .(Grouping, Age)][, 
        .(Proportion=sum(Gender=="F")/.N), Grouping]
```

Answer (score 2):

Try this. The idea is in the comment.

```
# group by Grouping,Age
# calculate sum(Value) and sum(Value) for Gender == "F"
dt1 <- DT[,
          .(sum(Value),
            .SD[Gender == "F",sum(Value)]
             ),
          keyby = .(Grouping,Age)]
# add column: number of gender F has a higher value
dt1[,NF:=fifelse(V2/V1>0.5,1,0),by = .(Grouping,Age)]
dt1[,.(sum(NF)/.N),by = Grouping]
```